# How secure is using https on android?

Tags: android, security, https

If I have an app on the store, is it possible to download it and use the debugger and introspection or some other technique to see the unencrypted Strings requests inside the app? If yes, what could help to prevent such techniques?

Comment: HTTPS provides end-to-end encryption. i.e. It's secure between the client and server. It provides no protection beyond that. Either end can do as they wish. You cannot protect the user from themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If I have an app on the store, is it possible to download it and use the debugger and introspection or some other technique to see the unencrypted Strings requests inside the app?

Sure.

> If yes, what could help to prevent such techniques?

Stop writing software for end users.

Software that resides purely on a server somewhere can be assumed to be relatively safe from inspection. Software that runs on user equipment -- whether that is JavaScript in a Web browser, an Android app, a Windows desktop app, or whatever -- is subject to analysis. Different environments may make analysis easier or harder, so it is generally easier to inspect the goings-on of a Web app than it is for an Android app, etc. Obfuscation, such as that offered by ProGuard, will help incrementally, as can writing your HTTP logic in native C/C++ code, but neither approach is proof from reverse-engineering, let alone debugging.

Note that this has little to do with HTTPS, as the same statements hold for anything done by any program.

Comment: Aww, was aiming more for an answer like "all android apps run in safe containers that cannot be inspected", maybe with strings attached so you have to set compiler flags or whatever .. thx for the clarification! So basically one should only use the app as thin client for touch events and view drawing while the real "app" runs on the server?

Comment: @DanielBrown: "So basically one should only use the app as thin client for touch events and view drawing while the real "app" runs on the server?" -- there will be apps for which this is an appropriate model, just not that many. There are other solutions that many will turn to, such as controlling distribution of the app, so that the people who have the app have no particular need or interest in doing these sorts of attacks.